# How to set the thumbnail size of Responsive filemanager?

Tags: responsive-filemanager

I want to increase the thumbnail size of responsive filemanager, anyone knows how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to change the thumbnail size of Responsive filemanager V9, tryout the code in the file `UploadHandler.php` at line 1440:

```
$thumbResult = create_img($targetFile, $targetFileThumb, 122, 91);
```

become to:

```
$newWidth = 400;
$newHeight = 300;
$thumbResult = create_img($targetFile, $targetFileThumb, $newWidth, $newHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `responsive_filemanager` → filemanager → config → `multiple_thumb.php` and add thumbnail size you want.

Reference: https://riamedia.vn/blog/responsive-filemanager-9-14-0-with-multiple-thumbs.html